# check whether cursor is at first/last position in contenteditable

Tags: position, contenteditable, caret

Is there a simple way of checking, whether the caret is at the very first, or last position in a contenteditable? I know that there are ways of getting the caret position, e.g., [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container), but I was wondering, whether there is a simpler method, if I only want to know if the caret is at the top/bottom of the div.

What I try to do is to automatically move the caret to the previous/next div, if it has reached the top/bottom of the currently focused div. The HTML structure is simply

```
<div contenteditable=true id="div1">something here</div>
<div contenteditable=true id="div2">something else</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v923z/92FWk/

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7478420/96100

Comment: Thank, Tim, this looks interesting. So, the bottom line is that there is no native method/functions for this, one has to mess with selections/ranges.