# Stop unwanted scrolling when moving caret with arrow keys in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors, keydown

Keydown works perfectly when I select `document`, `*`, `body` or any particular element.

But when I add `.not('.some-class')`, keydown works like this `.not()` doesn't even exist. Maybe because of the way keydown affects children elements, but I'm not sure:

```
$('*').not('.some-class').on('keydown',function(e){ 
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    if(key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {}
});
```

How to disable these keys for the whole document except for 1 child class?

**edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/umL139xw/2/

How to stop this unwanted scrolling while keeping ability to move caret with arrows?

**edit2:** complete solution thanks to Jason P and Kaiido

**http://jsfiddle.net/umL139xw/5/**

Comment: Try `$('*:not(.some-class)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cursor's position detector from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451468/contenteditable-div-how-can-i-determine-if-the-cursor-is-at-the-start-or-end-o/7478420#7478420)** and then `preventDefault()` only when you're at the end.

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
    console.log(this, e.target);
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    if(key == 16 || key == 32 || key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {}
});
$('.b').on('keydown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
   //Above part comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451468/contenteditable-div-how-can-i-determine-if-the-cursor-is-at-the-start-or-end-o/7478420#7478420
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    post_range = document.createRange();
    post_range.selectNodeContents(this);
    post_range.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    next_text = post_range.cloneContents();

    if( next_text.textContent.length === 0 && key == 39 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/umL139xw/4/)**

Comment: fantastic! if anybody wonders how to disable key, for ex. page up, regardless of the position, just do this: `if( next_text.textContent.length === 0,1 && key == 34 )`

Answer (score 1):

Events bubble (well, a good number of them do). That means they fire on the target of the event, then on every element up the DOM tree, so even if you don't bind the handler to `.some-class`, it will fire for that element's ancestors. Also, binding an event handler to `*` is generally not a good idea. Maybe something like this would work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/j3wqpdow/

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){ 
    console.log(this, e.target);
});

$('.some-class').on('keydown', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: this works in the fiddle. however, keys still affect the page (scrolling). how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/umL139xw/1/ works, but that scrolling problem I want to remove remains. maybe I should reformulate the question. edit: hold right arrow.

Comment: Chrome won't scroll the page, however in Firefox, with B (using stopPropagation), it will scroll the page when the end of the text is reached.